# Mostrar error de validação na View

Tags: php, mvc

Estou com um problema, não consigo mostrar o erro na validação de formulários na View (MVC feito por mim) corretamente, ele está mostrando em local errado, gostaria que ficasse em cima do botão ou a baixo.

Model:

```
<?php

class Login_Model extends Model {

    public $_errorVal;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function login() {
        if (isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {
            try {

                $form = new Form();

                $form->post('username')
                     ->val('required')

                 ->post('password')
                 ->val('required');

                $this->_errorVal = $form->submit();

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
<?php

class Login extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {

        $this->view->title = 'Nome da Web - login';

        $this->model->login();

        $this->view->formValidation = $this->model->_errorVal;

        $this->view->render('header');
        $this->view->render('login/index');
        $this->view->render('footer');
    }
}
```

View:

```
<section class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Usuário" class="form-control">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Senha" class="form-control">
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-right">
                                <button type="submit" name="btn-login" class="btn btn-success">Entrar</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <?php
                            if (isset($this->formValidation)) {
                                echo $this->formValidation;
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Imagem de como está imprimindo na tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero que a mensagem seja exibida abaixo do botão entrar ou em cima dele.
Obs: não quero fazer uso de Frameworks então se alguém sugerir vou apenas ignorar certo?

O código do projeto está no GitHub: [Projeto aqui](https://github.com/GuiAlves2708/MVC-with-php)

Comment: Tem certeza que a variavel `$this->view->formValidation` esta sentando o valor?

Comment: Então, não tem outra lógica para se fazer isso, pelo menos eu não encontrei... ao debugar usando `var_dump();` me retorna null e não sei como proceder :/, de todos os casos coloquei um link do projeto no github pro pessoal tentar me ajudar.

Comment: Sua arquitetura é um pouco confusa, mas acho que consegui responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja que `submit()` não esta retornando nada, só o `true` em caso de sucesso:

```
public function submit()
{
    if (empty($this->_error)) 
    {
        return true;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $str = '';
        foreach ($this->_error as $key => $value)
        {
            $str .= ucfirst($key) . ' ' . $value . "<br/>";
        }
        throw new Exception($str);
    }
}
```

No entanto aqui você tenta pegar o valor dele, Isso é desnecessário por que no máximo ele vai pegar o `true`:

```
$this->_errorVal = $form->submit();
```

Já aqui você disparou um `echo` em caso de `throw new Exception`

```
    $this->_errorVal = $form->submit();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

O correto me parece capturar o erro assim:

```
try {
    $form = new Form();

    $form->post('username')
         ->val('required')

     ->post('password')
     ->val('required');

    $form->submit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->_errorVal = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Funcionou, mas aquela dúvida ainda fica no ar, o `catch` não deixa o código enviar?

Comment: @GuilhermeSpinXO não esta problema no `catch`, veja o seu `submit` não retornava nada só tinha o `throw new Exception($str);`, não vai exibir nada porque não retornou nada, e as mensagens de erro de validação apareciam em cima de tudo porque você usou `echo` no `catch` quando deveria ter setado a variavel, não sei se consegui ser claro.

Comment: Tudo certo então muito obrigado.